# Storing JSON file as itself in MYSQL DB

Tags: mysql, json

I have a JSON file which will have more keys and its respective values. To parse & insert all the data into a MySQL is not possible and it would be very difficult to create the table structures in DB. How can we store the entire JSON file as itself into MySQL?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html did you check this? you have similar questions on SO as well.

Comment: Certainly that is possible, why not? A file is nothing but a string or maybe blob data. So create a column of blob type and go! Things are different if you want to selectively access single "cells" inside that JSON structure by means of JSON. That is a whole different topic! For that you need an extension of the mysql server which is still experimental (AFAIK) and certainly extremely slow.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to store and retrieve the JSON file and not do anything else with it, a normal [TEXT data type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/blob.html) is sufficient.

[MySQL 5.7.8 added a JSON data type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html) and a [host of functions to create, modify, and search them](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-functions.html). This is the most efficient way to store and work with JSON data in MySQL. [PostgreSQL also has this feature](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-json.html).

If you don't have MySQL 5.7, consider upgrading. If you can't upgrade, consider using a [document store NoSQL database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document-oriented_database) like MongoDB or CouchDB rather than a relational SQL server. They are designed to deal with ad hoc data like JSON.